# Would a Polymorphic Association be worth it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

An app I'm working on needs to have 'Before photos' and 'After photos'. Right now it has 2 separate tables in the database. I'm thinking of merging these 2 so it would look something like this:

```
create_table :photos do |t|
    t.string  :image
    t.string  :photographable_type
end
```

And maybe have something like this in my model

```
has_many :before_photos, class_name: 'Photo', as: :photographable
has_many :after_photos, class_name: 'Photo', as: :photographable
```

I've never had to use a Polymorphic Association before and am a bit confused. Could someone give me a run down as to what's the correct way of doing this and explain it a bit?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's a great railscast here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association. Could you explain about before/after photos? Are they models? What is before/after referring to? If this is simply two versions of the same image, one before, the other after, I wouldn't even use two models. I'd use two image columns/uploaders. Polymorphic makes sense if that list of `photographable_types` is likely to grow or there is great duplication between two models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use conditional `has_many` instead of polymorphic associations like that:

```
class PhotoOwner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :before_photos, -> { where some_field: true }, class_name: 'Photo'
  has_many :after_photos, -> { where some_field: false }, class_name: 'Photo'
end
```

Get it from here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html, section 'Customizing the query`